# AdWords Keyword Insertion in Destination URLs

Tags: google-ads

I cannot for the life of me get keyword insertion in my destination URLs to work. I want to have the keyword appear in the destination URL. I've tried turning off autotagging, and have tried all of the following as destination URLs:

```
www.myhomepage.com/?keyword={keyword}
www.myhomepage.com/?keyword={keyword:defaulttext}
www.myhomepage.com/index.php?keyword={keyword}
www.myhomepage.com/index.php?keyword={keyword:defaulttext}
```

In each case, my ad has been approved, and then I've clicked on it myself. In each case, clicking on the ad takes me to www.myhomepage.com. Any parameters are obliterated. Weirdly, "index.php" is also obliterated.

I tried emailing AdWords support and they didn't reply. I tried calling them, but the person I spoke to had very limited technical knowledge and wasn't any help.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong/or if it's possible to do what I want?

Comment: Those all should work. Any chance you have destination URLs set at the keyword level? Those will overrule the URLs set at the ad level.

Comment: @EricBrandel: Maybe this is it, I'm not sure. My marketing company does the AdWords for me, so I'm not very competent with it. However, I worked out that the destination URLs I was setting were not being used. So maybe what you are suggesting is what's happening. I'll see if I can find out. Thanks.

Comment: @EricBrandel: BTW, do you know if I need auto-tagging disabled to get the above destination URLs to work?